# Shallow copy of a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, clone, shallow-copy

As I understand it, there are a couple of ways (maybe others as well) to create a shallow copy of a `Map` in Java:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> shallowCopy;

// first way
shallowCopy = new HashMap<String, Object>(data);

// second way
shallowCopy = (Map<String, Object>) ((HashMap<String, Object>) data).clone();
```

Is one way preferred over the other, and if so, why?

One thing worth mentioning is that the second way gives an "Unchecked Cast" warning. So you have to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to get around it, which is a little irritating (see below).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, Object> getDataAsMap() {
    // return a shallow copy of the data map
    return (Map<String, Object>) ((HashMap<String, Object>) data).clone();
}
```

Comment: In the newer versions of Java (since Java 10, to be exact) you can use the [Map.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) static factory method. But note that it returns an unmodifiable Map!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It's always better to copy using a copy constructor. `clone()` in Java is broken (see SO: [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method/2326801#2326801)).

[Josh Bloch on Design - Copy Constructor versus Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you read between the lines, you will know that I think `clone` is deeply broken. [...] It's a shame that `Cloneable` is broken, but it happens.

Bloch (who by the way, designed and implemented the Collection framework) even went further in saying that he only provides the `clone()` method just "because people expect it". He does NOT actually recommend using it at all.

---

I think the more interesting debate is whether a copy constructor is better than a copy factory, but that's a different discussion altogether.

Comment: Yep, this is one of my favorite parts of the book.

Comment: I don't like to say that clone() is broken. I prefer to say that clone was a terrible design decision and can harm you a lot if you don't use it properly. Also, you might never trust other people clone() methods. So we end up similar, try to avoid it, but it's not broken.

Comment: Doesn't using the copy ctor require you to know which implementation of Map you're copying? Seems like an unnecessary limitation.

Comment: "that he only provides the clone() method just "because people expect it"" -- source?

Answer (score 62):

Neither of the two: the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28java.util.Map%29) that you are referring to is defined for the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implementation of a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), (as well as for others) but not for the Map interface itself (for example, consider the [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) implementation of the Map interface: you will not find that constructor).

On the other hand it is not advisable to use the `clone()` method, as explained by Josh Bloch.

In respect of the Map interface (and of your question, in which you ask how to copy a Map, not a HashMap), you should use [Map#putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29):

> Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map
>   (optional operation). The effect of this call is equivalent to that of
>   calling put(k, v) on this map once for each mapping from key k to
>   value v in the specified map.

Example:

```
// HashMap here, but it works for every implementation of the Map interface
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> shallowCopy = new HashMap<String, Object>();

shallowCopy.putAll(data);
```

Comment: So then to clarify: if you *know* are copying *to* an implementation of `Map` which has a copy constructor there is no reason to not use the copy constructor then?

Comment: Exactly, and you can even think it the other way around: if you use `putAll` you _do not need to know_ if the `Map` implementation you are using has a copy constructor or not. A merely copy constructor of any `Map` implementation is thus redundant.

Comment: Sure, though generally I like 1-liners better than 2-liners. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Copy a map without knowing its implementation:

```
static final Map shallowCopy(final Map source) throws Exception {
    final Map newMap = source.getClass().newInstance();
    newMap.putAll(source);
    return newMap;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding `<K,V>` type parameters to help ensure type safety.

Comment: What about maps without zero-argument constructors?