# Eclipse warning "Type safety: Unchecked cast" has got recursive solutions

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, hashmap, shallow-copy

In my case I have this to manipulate a shallow copy of given HashMap

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
    public SomeClass( private HashMap<String, String> hashMap )
    {
        this.hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) hashMap.clone();
    }
}
```

However eclipse suggests me to extract to local variable or method or add a cast and when I do so it keeps suggesting me same solutions :)

I've came to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast) and from the accepted answer I dont find it very clear

> "you're wasting memory with the new HashMap creation call"

And when I apply that to my code I'll have

```
if(songData.clone() instanceof HashMap)
{
    this.songData = (HashMap<String, String>) songData.clone();
}
```

I find that cosume more process as calling `clone()` twice.

Is there a better way to do this? Could my snippet be harmful to resouces?

Comment: The "you're wasting memory with the new HashMap creation call" refers to the `new` in the `private Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();` Your code does not have this problem.

Comment: Logically, you don't need to do the `instanceof` check here since `HashMap#clone()` will always return an object of type `HashMap`. However since it indirectly overrides `Object#clone()` the actual return type of the `HashMap#clone()` method is `Object` and not `HashMap` which is why you're getting a warning. I personally would not worry about the warning.

Comment: Yes thanks, Is there a better way to achieve this from memory, speed and reliability wise?

Comment: I would probably just use `new HashMap<String, String>(hashMap)` instead of using `clone()` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356809/shallow-copy-of-a-map-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use clone.  `clone()` is a badly designed method that requires too much knowledge of the object being cloned and is often implemented wrong by users anyway. (See *Effective Java* for more info about this)

The best way to copy the Map is to create a new map with the same data:

```
public SomeClass( HashMap<String, String> hashMap )
{
    this.hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>(hashMap);
}
```

Also as an FYI, `public SomeClass( private HashMap<String, String> hashMap )` doesn't compile.  You can't have parameters with a `private` keyword. Removing "private" from the parameter works.

**you're wasting memory with the new HashMap call**

This was in the answer to the other post you referenced because their code was:

```
private Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
someMap = (HashMap<String, String>)...
```

Where `someMap` was created with a call to `new Hashmap()` but then that reference was immediately replaced with a different HashMap.

It is irrelevant to your problem so you can ignore it.

Comment: What about the copy constructor itself? in official documentation they say to use clone for a shallow copy, and said nothing about copy constructor, and I can't try it now to test. btw "private" in argument was pasted by mistake :)

Comment: I also like the `putAll()` solution on second answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356809/shallow-copy-of-a-map-in-java but I've got no idea about its performance