# How to copy an object by value, not by reference

Tags: java

I want to make a copy of an object, then after some logic, re-assign the original object the value of the copy.

example:

```
User userCopy = //make a copy

foreach(...)
{
  user.Age = 1;
  user.ID = -1;

  UserDao.Update(user)


  user = userCopy; 

}
```

I don't want a copy by reference, it has to be a copy by value.

The above is just a sample, not how I really want to use it but I need to learn how to copy by value.

Answer (score 40):

Here are the few techniques I've heard of:

1. Use `clone()` if the class implements `Cloneable`. This API is a bit flawed in java and I never quite understood why `clone` is not defined in the interface, but in `Object`. Still, it might work.
2. Create a clone manually. If there is a constructor that accepts all parameters, it might be simple, e.g `new User( user.ID, user.Age, ... )`. You might even want a constructor that takes a User: `new User( anotherUser ).`
3. Implement something to copy from/to a user. Instead of using a constructor, the class may have a method `copy( User )`. You can then first snapshot the object `backupUser.copy( user )` and then restore it `user.copy( backupUser )`. You might have a variant with methods named `backup`/`restore`/`snapshot`.
4. Use the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).
5. Use [serialization](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html?ca=drs-). If your object is a graph, it might be easier to serialize/deserialize it to get a clone.

That all depends on the use case. Go for the simplest.

**EDIT**

I also recommend to have a look at these questions:

- [Clone() vs. Copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)
- [How to properly override clone method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method/2326801#2326801)

Answer (score 14):

You may use  `clone()` which works well if your object has immutable objects and/or primitives, but it may be a  little problematic when you don't have these ( such as collections ) for which you may need to perform a deep clone.

```
User userCopy = (User) user.clone();//make a copy

for(...) {
    user.age = 1;
    user.id = -1;

    UserDao.update(user)
    user = userCopy; 
}
```

It seems like you just want to preserve the attributes: `age` and `id` which are of type `int` so, why don't you give it a try and see if it works.

For more complex scenarios you could create a "copy" method:

```
publc class User { 
    public static User copy( User other ) {
         User newUser = new User();
         newUser.age = other.age;
         newUser.id = other.id;
         //... etc. 
         return newUser;
    }
}
```

It should take you about 10 minutes.

And then you can use that instead:

```
     User userCopy = User.copy( user ); //make a copy
     // etc.
```

To read more about clone read this chapter in Joshua Bloch ["Effective Java: Override clone judiciously"](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=implements+clone+judiciously&source=bl&ots=yXJgInt0P4&sig=nPdlgUKMyt0Lx8eDpUpb__vyg90&hl=en&ei=E2TDS7anLMH68AbLrfz_CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=implements%20clone%20judiciously&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

I believe `.clone()` is what you're looking for, so long as the class supports it.

Comment: Cough, cough. We all know clone is evil:)

Comment: It isn't evil, it's just misunderstood. It means well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little bit too late but it might just help someone.

In my case I already had a method to make the Object from a json Object and make json from the object. with this you can simply create a new instance of the object and use it to restore. For instance in a function parsing a final object

```html
public void update(final Object object){ 
  final Object original = Object.makeFromJSON(object.toJSON()); 
  // the original is not affected by changes made to object 
}
```

Comment: This Does work..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just make a copy constructor? By the way Java always passes references by value, so you keep pointing to the same object.

Comment: Actually... Java always passes by value.  It's just that, for non-primitives, the value is a reference.

Comment: Java doesn't pass references by reference. Java passes references by value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a deep copy from user to usercopy, and then after your login you can reassign your userCopy reference to user.

```
User userCopy = new User();
userCopy.Age = user.Age
userCopy.ID = user.ID

foreach(...) 
{ 
  user.Age = 1; 
  user.ID = -1; 

  UserDao.Update(user)     

  user = userCopy;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what language is this? If you're using a language that passes everything by reference like Java (except for native types), typically you can call `.clone()` method. The .clone() method is typically implemented by copying/cloning all relevant instance fields into the new object.