# java: "downcasting" to new object / opposite of slicing

Tags: java, downcast

Sorry, i really dont know how to make a headline for that question; maybe there is a name for what im trying to do that i dont know, but i can explain it with some code:

Guess you have a class that unfortunately neither has a copy-constructor nor a public static copy method.

```
class A
{
    private int i;  // <- private, cant access
    String x;       // <- even worse: cant access unless in same pkg!
    /* … other stuff, ctor, etc. … */
    public A clone()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.i = i;
        a.x = x;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Guess further, there is some function that returns an object of that class:

```
public static A someFn(x,y,z);
```

Now the problem: I want to derive from that class to add some functionality. Unfortunately, i neither have a sizeof in java nor a cc or static copy method.

So when i do a

```
class B extends A
{
    protected w;
    public B clone()
    {
       /* as usual */
    }
}
```

then i can clone my B and get a new one, but how can i convert the returned A from someFn() into a B. Is there anyway to do the opposite of slicing in java? if i clone it, it's still an A, and i cant copy it field by field. This is all simple in c++, but how to do this in Java?

Comment: Your example is a little too abstract. What sort of constructors does A have? How are those private and package-private fields set under normal circumstances?

Comment: what a messy question...

Comment: If you're talking about cloning in java-sense then when you call `super.clone()` in `B` you'll get `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way left was a complete wrapper mimicing the functionality i needed, buyed with some overhead in performance.

Its completly stupid that there is no way to provide a class for clone to clone into…

Answer (score 3):

Either change the design of A and B to be able to transform an A into a B (if it's even meaningful : how would you transform a dog into a dalmatian?), or use composition instead of inheritance :

```
public class B {
    private A a;
    private int w;

    public B(A a, int w) {
        this.a = a;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public int foo() {
        return a.foo();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Composition would be usefull if java would allow me to overload the cast-operator. I still need the possibility of giving a B for an A.

Comment: Then make A and B implement the same interface, and use this interface in the rest of your code rather than A. That's what interfaces are for.

Comment: to the dalmatian thing: Think you would want to transform a dog into a dog-that-has-an-ID.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would all the existing code using A would do with this additional ID it would have as a B instance, since the existing code doesn't know it has an ID property?

Comment: nothing. but i could use _the same_ object that has additional functionallity. The existing code takes As and provides some overridable fns where they're reappear. I can (and do) stuff Bs (extending A) in and they provide the same functionallity as As plus additional stuff. But then there some existing fns that _create_ As. And i want them to turn to Bs. they dont need to have the same mem location, but i need to copy the A-part into a B.

Answer (score 1):

In java, one does not implement `clone()` using operator `new`. I hope you have control over the original Java class - it is not adhering to best practices.

You call `super.clone()` instead which magically returns an object of the correct type, with the results of the previous clone methods applied to it.

See [How to properly override clone method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method).

Answer (score 1):

First, your clone method is wrong. It sould be something like:

```
public A clone(){
    A result = (A)super.clone();
    result.i = i;
    result.x = x;
    return result;
}
```

While the clone for B:

```
public B clone(){
    B result = (B)super.clone():
    result.w = w;
    return result;
}
```

You could have a constructor in B which takes an instance of A, pulls out the data it requires from that instance of A, and creates the B object with it.

Then, you could call someFn(x,y,z) like:

```
B b = new B(someFn(x, y, z))
```

Also if someFn wouldn't have been static, you could have written a subclass for the class that defines it, and override someFn changing it's return type like (this feature is called [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)):

```
B someFn(x, y, z){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy the fields from the original to the clone. super.clone() does it for you.