# How does clone work under the hood?

Tags: java, clone

Clone does not call the object constructor to create a copy of the object. So what  algorithm does clone use ?

I am looking for implementation details of the native method clone. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Note that I am aware of the shortcomings of clone.

Answer (score 3):

`protected native Object clone()`. I don't know exactly (I  need to take a look at the native code) but it makes a new instance of the object inside the JVM and copies all fields.

But you should avoid using `clone()` - it is hard to get it right. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance) for more details

Comment: hmm...I am thinking on the lines of how native implementation is done.

Answer (score 3):

How it works is laid out in [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> The method `clone` for class `Object` performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown. Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable. Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

E.g., a naive, shallow field-by-field copy, very nearly (but probably not quite) just a bit-for-bit copy of the object.

> I am looking for implementation details of the native method clone.

That will vary from JVM implementation to JVM implementation. It's likely to be quite an efficient operation, though, if that's your concern.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of JNI, `clone` is (or could be) implemented using the `AllocObject` method which creates a new object without invoking any constructor (as opposed to `NewObject`). When you have the new object, reflection is used to shallowly copy all fields.

But then again, the `clone`/`Clonable` mechanism is fundamentally broken in Java. Joshua Bloch has a section about it in [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/). There is also several related [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method) about it.

Comment: +1 for Joshua Block's link, but it is broken as well,just like clone feature. Here is something we can read directly : http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.clone()` implementation is a native method that checks that the object's class implements `Cloneable`, and then simply allocates a new instance and does a field-by-field shallow copy.  The copying is most likely done using a memory copy - there's no need for it to do anything more fancy.  (But if you really want to know, look at the OpenJDK source code.)