# In quest of source code: where is the clone() method of arrays implemented?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, clone

```java
new String[] { "foo", "bar" }.clone();
```

With my favorite IDE (i.e. Eclipse), I wanted to see the source code of the above `clone()` method by *Ctrl-clicking* on it (as usual), but it brought me to the `Object`'s native one, which provides only the signature and not the body of the method.

The autocomplete told me that the said `clone()` method belonged to the `String` class (`clone() : String[] - String`), but the source code of the `String` class doesn't provide such a method (since I'm dealing with the `String[]` class...).

So, where is that implementation hiding? Should the autocomplete be fixed?

Comment: you are calling clone on an array, not on a string.

Comment: `clone` is a `native` method of `java.lang.Object`, it works on all objects. Mandatory disclosure: [clone is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: Also please refer to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825982/how-does-clone-work-under-the-hood

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Note that the original question was about array-cloning, not object cloning (yes, I know arrays in Java are objects). But you can't implement a copy-constructor for an array, so... you use `[].clone()` or you use `System.arraycopy`. I see no downside to using `[].clone()`, and both Josh Bloch and Doug Lea agree that `[].clone()` is better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code for cloning an array is in the JVM (it is a native method). For hotspot, it is around lines 550/560 of [jvm.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp).

Comment: Some additional information about the native `Object.clone()` method: (1) it handles both array and non-array types (slightly differently); (2) it is essentially a wrapper around `memcpy()`, (3) any references in the cloned object are copied atomically, individually, but the clone itself is not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing is that Eclipse says that the `clone` method for a `String` array is in `String` class. But the `length` method of String array is from `String[]`.

[image]