# How can I create an instance of class without invoking constructor of this class?

Tags: java

There are some cases when we can create an instance without invoking a constructor of instance class. Any ideas what are these cases (Non *Reflection API*)?

Comment: Hi, could you edit and provide some code where you're finding this error?

Comment: this isnt possible becasue the constructor is what makes an object.

Comment: i don't have any idea. how could that be allowed to happen?

Comment: Maybe you think about invoking static methods which actually call the constructor like `Sets.newHashSet()` with Guava?

Comment: The example you are looking can be found on https://code.google.com/p/objenesis/, when here's no public constructor, you want to bypass the constructor code, or set final fields

Comment: You can create a `String` without ecplicitly invoking a constructor, using a literal.

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by invoking a constructor of this class? Because, as pointed out already at least one constructor in a classes' hierarchy (Object's constructor for example) will **ALWAYS** run, even when deserializing objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a sure way to break your system, but at least it **won't invoke the constructor**. Use `Unsafe#allocateInstance(Class)`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

public class Example {
    private String value = "42";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Example instance = (Example) unsafe.allocateInstance(Example.class);
        System.out.println(instance.value);
    }

    static Unsafe unsafe;
    static {
        try {

            Field singleoneInstanceField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            singleoneInstanceField.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe) singleoneInstanceField.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which prints

```
null
```

indicating that the `Example` default constructor wasn't invoked.

Comment: Going through Unsafe is just nasty ;)

Comment: Reflection is usually considered bad, Unsafe is just evil.

Comment: Interesting to note: if `value` is declared `final`, it **will** be initialized and then `"42"` will be printed.

Comment: @icza Not exactly. If you print it out with `instance.value`, it will print `"42"`, because it's a constant expression and was replaced at compile time. But if you retrieve it dynamically with a `Field` instance, it will actually be `null`.

Comment: @icza Similarly, if you declared it `final` and initialized it in a constructor, you would again see it `null`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, it's just a compiler optimization (although a false one in this case... even the compiler assumes a constructor will be called).

Comment: @barbara To clarify, this uses Reflection to get the `Unsafe` instance, but it doesn't use reflection to create the `Example` instance.

Comment: Reflection is not bad. Lots of libraries have a legitimate use for it. Writing a plugin system is one use. Unsafe should be avoided like the plague if you want high quality stable software. If it is a personal project or some sort of way out in left field project then do whatever it takes.

Answer (score 5):

Two "common" cases involving non-constructor based object creation are `deserialization` and `clone()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they don't use a constructor? Every instance has to be created through a constructor as far as I know, all these do is hide it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel No they don't hide it. It's JVM magic, the constructor is never called (which can be easily tested).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Isn't clone implemented by a native method?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825982/how-does-clone-work-under-the-hood

Comment: @barbara What do you mean it's not the "correct" answer?  Either you are saying this isn't right (then you should explain why) or you know the answer to your own question and are wasting peoples time.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware about `clone()`'s special case. As to deserialization I figured a default constructor was invoked and reflection used to fill its values, but I never explicitly looked into it.

Comment: @Andrew_CS About wasting other's time: not eactly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @icza That would be fine if the OP did that.

Answer (score 1):

The only cases that I can imagine are serialization and JNI.

With serialization, you create a new object by deserializing the whole object state from an input stream. No constructor is invoked in this case.

With JNI, there is the [AllocObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16337) function, which allocates the space for a new object, also without calling a constructor.

EDIT: A call to `clone()` may be considered as another case, but this depends on how the method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways of creating an instance of an Object

**1)** Through constructor using `new` keyword -The constructor should be accessible

**2)**  Through `serialization/deserialization`-The class should be Serializable;

**3)**  Through clone() method -The method should implement the marker interface Cloneable

**4)** Through reflection-You can access the constructor and create an instance without using the new keyword.The best thing about Reflection is that it can be used to instantiate Objects for private Constructors ,provided one does not mess up with SecurityManager

Comment: The Fifth Element: JNI

Comment: JNI is the best way I think. Especially when you are familiar with C.