# Cloning in Java

Tags: java

I read one paragraph from the Internet regarding cloning. But I didn't quite get it, so can someone explain it clearly?

> If the class has final fields, these can't be given a value in the clone method. This leads to problems with properly initializing the object's final fields. If the final field is referring to some internal state of the object, then the cloned object ends up sharing the internal state and this surely is not correct for mutable objects.

For reference, here is the link:
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/cloning.php

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method

Answer (score 20):

#### In short

- `o.clone()` calls `Object.clone()`, which makes a memory copy of `o`. Thereafter the copied references cannot be changed for final field, so we have involuntary aliasing;
- the unwanted aliasing and mutability do not go well with each other: If `o` changes, the clone involuntarily changes, too;
- the statements in [the blog post you cite](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/cloning.php) are copied from [this much better blog post](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm), which attests the statements with good code examples.

#### Details and examples about cloning via `Object.clone()'

I believe the article is talking about `clone()` via clone-chaining (via `super.clone()`), such that eventually `Object.clone()` is called, which makes a flat memory copy of the object being cloned via native code.

Let's say we have the following example (from [the blog post mentioned below](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm)):

```
public class Person implements Cloneable
{
    private final Brain brain; // brain is final since I do not want 
                // any transplant on it once created!
        // ...
}
```

and

```
person2 = (Person) person1.clone();
```

then person2 has the same memory-part for the field brain as person1, i.e. both hold the same reference to the same brain. Then since Person objects are mutable, they can learn things:

```
person1.learn(dvorakTyping);
```

then magically person2 can type on a dvorak keyboard as well. With immutable objects, this problem doesn't occur (though cloning's still problematic since final fields can still not be initialized via parameters, as in constructors).

#### Cloning via constructor calls

The reason for my very first half sentence: You can implement clone via calling one of the object's constructors. Some people claim this is against clone's contracts, but it isn't. Here's a [good blog post](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm) about why to call a constructor within clone (one main reason being those final fields).

---

#### Update

Reading Hemal's comment on mre's answer, I did glance over the blog post the question cited, and it turns out, the post copied some sentences from [the blog post I cited](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm), but without the very good code examples. LOL.

Comment: The link didn't make it to the final post. Please update. So basically what you are saying is that the memcpy is a bad implementation for clone? Well...yeah.

Comment: Yes, the memcpy-solution definitely has its deficiencies. But it has the (for me less important) advantage that subclasses need not override the clone() method to call their own constructor, since memcpy just takes the object - independent of what subclass it is from - and makes a memcpy.

Comment: agree completely -- being able to use memcpy is a very small benefit. Isn't this awfully similar to the C++ discipline of when you need a user defined copy-constructor?

Comment: I'm not that fit in C++, but I think their copy-constructors are closer to the advertised solution of calling a constructor within clone. In Java, I'm a big fan of copy- and conversion-constructors, and usually implement them via clone() - or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it either, except that a class cannot implement a well behaved `clone` method if all its fields don't also have a well behaved `clone` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I recommend it but one can use sun.misc.Unsafe to overwrite a value of a final field.
It is highly not recommended to use this class but this post is not about that ().
A sample code to overwrite a value of a final field:

```
    public class FinalClone
    implements Cloneable {
private final FinalClone finalField;

public FinalClone(FinalClone finalField) {
    this.finalField = finalField;
}

@Override
protected FinalClone clone()
        throws CloneNotSupportedException {

    final FinalClone result = (FinalClone) super.clone();

    if (finalField == null) {
        return result; // no need to clone null
    }

    final Field unsafeField;
    try {
        unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
    final Unsafe unsafe;
    try {
        unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new SecurityException(e);
    }

    // Update final field
    try {
        unsafe.putObjectVolatile(
                result,
                unsafe.objectFieldOffset(
                        FinalClone.class.getDeclaredField("finalField")),
                finalField.clone());
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: There is official support in the standard Reflection API for this kind of operation, so there is no need to use this non-standard internal class of a particular implementation. The clean solution would be even simpler…

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem in cloning final fields it works as for others but not effecitively all the time.

**Sometime it becomes problem for mutable objects**

When we use clone by default it gives shallow copy ( reference to same Object ) , so while overriding clone we try to deep copy all mutable objects.When we try to deep copy final fields problem occurs as final reference ( of final field ) can not be reassigned to new Object.

```
public class Person implements Cloneable
{
    private final Brain brain; 
    private int age;
    public Person(Brain aBrain, int theAge)
    {
        brain = aBrain; 
        age = theAge;
    }
    public Object clone()
    {
        try
        {
            Person another = (Person) super.clone();
            // shallow copy made so far. Now we will make it deep

            another.brain = (Brain) brain.clone();

//ERROR: you can't set another.brain 

            return another;
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {} 
        //This exception will not occur
    }

}
```

This example is from the same [blog](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm) mentioned in another answer by Davefar