# How to clone abstract objects with final fields in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class, clone

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378843/cloning-in-java) question and this [post](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm) is explained how to clone objects with final fields by using protected copy constructors.

However, supposing that we have:

```
public abstract class Person implements Cloneable
{
    private final Brain brain; // brain is final since I do not want 
                // any transplant on it once created!
    private int age;
    public Person(Brain aBrain, int theAge)
    {
        brain = aBrain; 
        age = theAge;
    }
    protected Person(Person another)
    {
        Brain refBrain = null;
        try
        {
            refBrain = (Brain) another.brain.clone();
            // You can set the brain in the constructor
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {}
        brain = refBrain;
        age = another.age;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "This is person with " + brain;
        // Not meant to sound rude as it reads!
    }
    public Object clone()
    {
        return new Person(this);
    }

    public abstract void Think(); //!!!!
    …
}
```

Returns an error since we can't instantiate an abstract class. How can we solve this?

Comment: When you bother to override `clone`, don't forget that you may make the return type more specific (`Person` instead of `Object`) and that it doesn't need to declare `throws CloneNotSupportedException` (you should probably do this for `Brain`).

Comment: I can't help but stop and think that your question effectively amounts to "How do I clone a Person?" and none of us think that's odd because we're programmers.

Comment: I think it is more a design problem. If all the possible implementation of Person class are unkwown, I would ask myself if using inheritance in this case is right.  
Can the problem be solved using composition? Which is a possible implementation of Person? Because if you can use composition, the solution is easy, it is just a call to the constructor of Person and set all the variable, otherwise, if inheritance is important, you know that you need a `Person clone()` method in Person, so declare it abstract and all the implementation will decide how to implement it. Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't implement the `clone()` method in the abstract class, only in the concrete sub-classes.

```
public class SomeConcretePerson extends Person
{
    public SomeConcretePerson (SomeConcretePerson another)
    {
        super (another); // this will invoke Person's copy constructor
    }

    public Object clone()
    {
        return new SomeConcretePerson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Eran: How is the abstract class aware of the existence of its child classes???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It's not aware of them and should not be aware of them.

Comment: Ok but....What a pain! Is that the only way? In that case I think I should declare `public abstract Object clone()` in `Person`, right?

Comment: @justHelloWorld You certainly can, but you don't have to.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: what would be the point of implementing `Cloneable`? It isn’t used here at all.

Answer (score 7):

In some rare cases, we might not be able to use the copy constructor technique and have to use the `clone()` method. For these cases, it’s worth knowing that Java offers a work-around for the `final` field problem:

```
public abstract class Person implements Cloneable {
    private final Brain brain;
    private int age;
    public Person(Brain aBrain, int theAge) {
        brain = aBrain; 
        age = theAge;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "This is person with " + brain;
        // Not meant to sound rude as it reads!
    }
    @Override public Person clone() {
        try {
            Person clone = (Person)super.clone();
            Field brainField=Person.class.getDeclaredField("brain");
            brainField.setAccessible(true);
            brainField.set(clone, brain.clone());
            return clone;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException|ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }
    }

    public abstract void think();

    …
}
```

The possibility to override the `final` restriction was created for exactly such use cases, cloning or deserializing an object, where no constructor will be called. The [Java Language Specification, §17.5.3. Subsequent Modification of `final` Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3) states:

> In some cases, such as deserialization, the system will need to change the `final` fields of an object after construction. `final` fields can be changed via reflection and other implementation-dependent means. The only pattern in which this has reasonable semantics is one in which an object is constructed and then the `final` fields of the object are updated. The object should not be made visible to other threads, nor should the `final` fields be read, until all updates to the `final` fields of the object are complete.

This is exactly how the example works, setting the `final` field right after the clone’s construction, before the clone is exposed to anyone, and not reading any field.

As said, cases in which this is required, are rare. As long as you can implement a copy constructor based solution, use that.

Comment: You forgot to mention that this solution (and any reflection based on reflection ftm) *breaks silently* whenever the affected fields are renamed, and this will become a problem not earlier than runtime.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: indeed, though the field and the `clone` method reside in the same class and audit tools should be able to check the correctness via static code analysis. But generally, using Reflection implies loosing compile-time checks…

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a new instance of the class without cloning the values of its members then you can use the following:

```
public  static < T > T getNewInstance ( Class <T> type )
{
    try 
    {
        return type.newInstance()  ;
    } catch ( InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null ;
}
```

For deep cloning of objects you can use **com.rits.cloning.Cloner** utility. For eg. :

```
private T clone(T resource){

    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
    T cloneObject = (T) cloner.deepClone(obj);
    return cloneObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't instantiate an abstract class but we can do it in the subClass

```
class Teacher extends Person {

    public Teacher(Brain aBrain, int theAge) {
        super(aBrain, theAge);
    }

    protected Teacher(Person another) {
        super(another);
    }


    public Object clone() {
        return new Teacher(this);
    }
}
```