# clone () implementation in Object class

Tags: java, clone

I was reading [this](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) article and it says that

> `Object`'s `clone` method is very tricky. It's based on field copies, and it's "extra-linguistic." It creates an object without calling a constructor".

All I see in the [grep code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#212) is the following line :

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `native` which means it's implemented in non-Java code (in this case it's implemented in the JVM itself).

That's because the exact functionality of `clone` *can not* be implemented in Java code (which makes it so problematic).

Comment: Why do you say that exact functionality of clone() can not be implemented in Java ?

Comment: @Subhra: as the article you linked to indicates, `clone()` creates a new object without ever invoking a constructor. There are only two mechanisms in Java that allow this: `clone()` and serialization. *Both* are implemented in native (non-Java) code. The only way that pure Java code can create objects (without those two mechanisms) is to use `new` (or the equivalent `Class.newInstance()`) and that *always* invokes a constructor.

Comment: +1 thanks for the clarification. But we can also use Reflection to create a new Instance without invoking constructor or am I wrong ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the creators of Java had not used `Cloneable` to decide whether an object should support memberwise cloning (having a native `Clone` method which was callable, but could throw an exception), instead simply defined a "native" class `CloneableObject` with a protected virtual ("native magic") `CloneBase` method, would the resulting framework have been any less expressive? Since `Object.Clone` is only (successfully) callable if the lowest-level class which extends `Object` has decided to implement `Cloneable`, it would seem that having such a class inherit `CloneableObject`...

Comment: ...would not place any restrictions on the design of such class, but would avoid the need for callers of `Clone` to catch a `nonImplemented` exception.

Comment: @Subhra To create a new instance with Reflection, you first get a `Constructor` object and then invoke `newInstance` on it. So you still invoke a constructor.

Comment: Basically, the only "sane" replacement for `clone()` is to write a copy constructor or a copy factory method.  (Effective Java makes this point better than I could, though.)

Comment: Could the downvoter tell me what's lacking in my answer, please?

Answer (score 4):

The `native` keyword indicates that the implementation is in native (non-Java) code.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to actually **understand** the concept behind `clone` better I recommend the answer to the question: [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method)

Regarding the source code you have put into your question:

`native` means here, that this is a method which is not implemented with Java, but with another language, often C or C++. It's still part of the JVM, hence you can find the actual implementation in the [OpenJDK™ Source Release](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) in the

```
"openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp":539

JVM_ENTRY(jobject, JVM_Clone(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_Clone");
  Handle obj(THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(handle));
  const KlassHandle klass (THREAD, obj->klass());
  JvmtiVMObjectAllocEventCollector oam;
  .
  .
  .
JVM_END
```

Answer (score 2):

The method is marked as `native`, so you cannot see its implementation because it is not in `Java`.