# updating a class within a class

Tags: java, class, user-interface, program-entry-point

is there a way to update a class I am currently in with a new instance of that class?
For example:

```
public class Test
{
  Test temp = new Test();
  this = temp;
}
```

I am doing this because I have a save/load feature form serializable and I need a way to update the current class from it

Comment: Uh... I think the code you provided works, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I want to recreate the class like update everything in it with the new "temp" from my load method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Java variables store references to objects, so `this = ...` will not work. There is no way for Java to track down every place that refers to the current instance of `Temp` and change the memory  reference that they point to.

The next-best thing may be to copy all of the fields from one object to another. [That has its own set of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method), though.