# Where can we use Object.clone() method in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method)

Can anyone give me any example where we can use the same?

Comment: http://www.javadb.com/how-to-clone-objects

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method) go through this. -1 for lack of research

Answer (score 0):

there might be situations when you plan to modify the object, and you don't want to modify the method caller's object. If you decide that you need a local copy, you can perform the operation by using the clone() method of the Object class.

Comment: Can you give me any practical situation example where it will be required?