# how to transfer contents from previous hashmap to a new hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
  HashMap<String,Integer> map= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  map.put("first",1);
  map.put("second",2);
  map.put("third",3);

  HashMap<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  map2= map.clone();
```

My question is how do I transfer items from map to map2? Is my code right?

Answer (score 7):

It is simple.Use parametrized constructor

```
  HashMap<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<String,Integer>(map);
```

Comment: In a perfect world `Map<String,Integer> map2 = ...` - it's preferable to use interfaces where possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map2.putAll(map);
```

or

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<String,Integer>(map);
```

Note that in both methods, the keys and values are not duplicated but just referenced by both `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking **deep copy** of your previous map use copy constructor, *clone is  a shallow copy of this HashMap instance: the keys and values themselves are not cloned*.

If you want **shallow copy** of your previous map you could use `pass the map reference to your new map constructor` rather than `clone` method.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<>(map);
```

There are annoyance over clone method find  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method/2326801#2326801).

[Josh Bloch on Design - Copy Constructor versus Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you
>   read between the lines, you will know that I think clone is deeply
>   broken. [...] It's a shame that Cloneable is broken, but it happens.