# Copy lists of objects with list members

Tags: java, object, arraylist, clone

How can i copy a `ArrayList` containing objects with `ArrayList` members. Also it might be possible, that the members of the objects in the list also containing again `ArrayList` members, and so on. So is there a generic way to copy list of objects regardless of their members?

Implementing the `Clone Interface` for all involved objects seems to be a bad idea, since [I read that its broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326801/1965084).

I created a small SSCCE to exemplify my problem:

```
class Foobar {
    public List<String> listMember;
    public String       primitiveMember;

    public Foobar() {
        listMember = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
        primitiveMember = "testABC";
    }
}
// Create list of Foobar
List<Foobar> foobars = new ArrayList<Foobar>();
foobars.add(new Foobar());
// Copy list of Foobar
List<Foobar> foobarsCopy = new ArrayList<Foobar>();
foobarsCopy.add(null);
Collections.copy(foobarsCopy, foobars);
// Modify source list
foobars.get(0).listMember.add("-1-");
// Output of references
System.out.println("Sourcelist has size of: " + foobars.get(0).listMember.size());
System.out.println("Destinationlist has size of: " + foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.size());
System.out.println("Function 'Collections.copy(...) does not copy list members of members?: " + (foobars.get(0).listMember.size() == foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.size()) + " - References: " + foobars.get(0).listMember.hashCode() + " vs " + foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.hashCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a copy constructor, if you don't want to use the cloneable interface. This way you get new Objects for each instance of the List elements, and a independent reference of the copied List. In short you will have a deep copy of the Foobar elements.

```
class Foobar {
    public List<String> listMember;
    public String       primitiveMember;

    public Foobar() {
        listMember = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
        primitiveMember = "testABC";
    }

    public Foobar(List<String> list, String primitive) {
        this.listMember = list;
        this.primitiveMember = primitive;
    }

    // Use a copy constructor instead of the Cloneable interface
    public Foobar(Foobar foobar) {
        this.primitiveMember = foobar.primitiveMember;
        this.listMember = new ArrayList<String>(foobar.listMember);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create list of Foobar
        List<Foobar> foobars = new ArrayList<Foobar>();
        foobars.add(new Foobar());

        // Copy list of Foobar with the copy constructor
        List<Foobar> foobarsCopy = new ArrayList<Foobar>(foobars.size());
        for (Foobar f : foobars) {
            foobarsCopy.add(new Foobar(f));
        }

        // add a new Foobar instance (hashcode will be different now)
        foobarsCopy.add(new Foobar(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f")), "foo"));

        // Modify source list (hashcode again will be different)
        foobars.get(0).listMember.add("-1-");

        // Output of references
        System.out.println("Sourcelist has size of: " + foobars.get(0).listMember.size());
        System.out.println("Destinationlist has size of: " + foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.size());
        System.out.println("Function 'Collections.copy(...) does not copy list members of members?: "
                + (foobars.get(0).listMember.size() == foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.size()) 
                + "\n - References: " + foobars.get(0).listMember.hashCode() 
                + " vs " + foobarsCopy.get(0).listMember.hashCode());

    }

}
```

Comment: oK, your solution looks great, the copy constructor seems to be a good way to solve my problem. But i think the following line in your example is not necessary: foobarsCopy.add(new Foobar(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f")), "foo"));

Comment: No, it's not necessary. I added it to modify the copy of the List, I thought this way it would be more clear what is going on...