# Understanding what happens when we override the clone method with and without invoking super.clone?

Tags: java, cloneable

I'm reading Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. I must say its a dense and complex book. The chapter on Methods Common to all objects (chapter 3) is proving hard for me to grasp as I've been programming for less than 3 years (1 year in java). I don't quite understand the concept of overriding the clone method appropriately. Can I get a simple to follow example of implementing clone, the right way as well as the wrong way? And why failing to invoke super.clone would cause a problem? what will happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Java's `clone` is basically broken. Josh Bloch himself said the following: *"If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you read between the lines, you will know that I think clone is deeply broken. [...] It's a shame that Cloneable is broken, but it happens"* (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method)).

Comment: It's not clear what you are proposing when you say "without invoking super.clone". Where would you get the new object from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `super.clone()`. If you don't, and say just `return new MyObject(this.x);`, then that works fine for instances of MyObject. But if someone extends MyObject, it's no longer possible for them to get an instance of the right class when overriding your `clone` method. The one thing Object.clone does that you can't do a good job of yourself is creating an instance of the right class; the rest is just copying instance fields, which is drudgework you could have done yourself if you wanted.

Comment: thank you. So whats the rule of thumb here? If I override the objects clone method in my personal class, then in my implementation of the clone method I better add to the top of that method, `super.clone()`? And if I choose to extend that class a few hierarchies down, I better make sure in each of my classes, I override object's clone method and in each override at the top add just `super.clone()`? And everything will be fine and dandy??

Comment: @TazMan: You don't just randomly write `super.clone();` at the top of a method. Rather, you use that to get the new object. If you don't use that, where would you get the new object from? amalloy's answer addresses the problem if you use `new CurrentClass()` to do it. What other alternative is there? Regarding overriding in subclasses, methods are inherited, so a subclass doesn't need to override the method unless it needs to do something additional to what the superclass's version does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading that book myself.  Not sure if I did everything "right" in this example, but maybe it'll help you understand.

Computer.java

```
package testclone;

public class Computer implements Cloneable {
    String OperatingSystem;

    protected Computer Clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Computer newClone = (Computer) super.clone();
        newClone.OperatingSystem = this.OperatingSystem;
        return newClone;
    }

}
```

MultiCore.java

```
package testclone;

public class MultiCore extends Computer implements Cloneable {
    int NumberOfCores;

    @Override
    protected MultiCore Clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
     //*********  use 1 of the next 2 lines  ***********           
        //MultiCore newClone = (MultiCore) super.clone();
        MultiCore newClone = new MultiCore();
        newClone.NumberOfCores = this.NumberOfCores;
        return newClone;
    }
}
```

TestClone.java

```
package testclone;

public class TestClone implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //Computer myComputer = new Computer();
        //myComputer.OperatingSystem = "Windows";

        MultiCore myMultiCore = new MultiCore();
        myMultiCore.OperatingSystem = "Windows";    //field is in parent class
        myMultiCore.NumberOfCores = 4;

        MultiCore newMultiCore = myMultiCore.Clone();

        System.out.println("orig Operating System  = " + myMultiCore.OperatingSystem);
        System.out.println("orig Number of Cores   = " + myMultiCore.NumberOfCores);
        System.out.println("clone Operating System = " + newMultiCore.OperatingSystem);
        System.out.println("clone Number of Cores  = " + newMultiCore.NumberOfCores);

    }

}
```

Output:

orig Operating System  = Windows

orig Number of Cores   = 4

clone Operating System = null       *****  This line is not what you want.

clone Number of Cores  = 4

If you use the super.clone() line instead, then the Output is

orig Operating System  = Windows

orig Number of Cores   = 4

clone Operating System = Windows    *****  Now it's what you want

clone Number of Cores  = 4

So if you don't use super.clone(), it doesn't clone the fields in the parent (or grandparent, or great-grandparent, etc)

Good luck!
(Sorry - the above looked formatted correctly when I typed it in, but for some reason looks awful when it actually shows)